# How to automatically open a file when Emacs start?

Tags: emacs, automation

How to automatically open a file when Emacs start?  I need this to work on Mac OS X and Linux, with GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) or a more recent version.  Also, I am using the `.app` version on Mac.

Edit:

Also, how to let it be opened in a specific window?  I want my Emacs to automatically have the frame split vertically and horizontally and therefore have 4 windows. And the file should show up in top left window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this at the end of your .emacs file:

```
(find-file "put the path to your file here")
```

Comment: To clarify, you keep the double quotes around the path, correct?

Comment: Also, how to let it be opened in a specific window?  I want my Emacs to automatically have split vertically and horizontally and have 4 windows. And the file should show up in top left window.

Answer (score 1):

well to make a frame horizontal you do `C-x-2` which i believe is switch-window-keep-point, so you could add that then add (find file "/")`

Comment: No there is no `switch-window-keep-point`.   I tried.

Comment: sorry its split-window-vertically just type in "C-h-k" then a key binding, then it will give you information about that key binding